# In Python is augmented addition of sets are not supported?

Tags: python, set

In the Python sets, why augmented removal of elements are supported but addition is not supported?

For example if `s` is a mutable set:

```
s = set(['e', 'd', 'h', 's'])
```

`s -= set('ds')` gives `s = set(['e', 'h'])`

but this does not work for `s += set('pk')` and results in `TypeError`.

Comment: Works fine for me (2.6).

Comment: With `-`, you remove elements from the set. You cannot add them via `+`, maybe the reason for this is, that this might suggest, you can have `e` in your set two times, this is why it's more straightforward to use `|`. This is just my own interpretation though :)

Answer (score 11):

The correct syntax for what you want to do is

```
s |= set('ds')
```

For sets, the binary operators `|`, `&` and `^` are used for union, intersection and symmetric difference, respectively. I guess the reason `+` is not considered a valid set operation is because it is not used [in set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations), while `-` is.

There's a nice symmetry between the way these three binary operators work on integers and the way they work on sets:

```
set("1234")  & set("1456") == set(['1', '4'])
bin(0b111100 & 0b100111)   == '0b100100'
#     1234       1  456          1  4

set("14")    | set("456")  == set(['1', '5', '4', '6'])
bin(0b100100 | 0b000111)   == '0b100111'
#     1  4          456          1  456

set("14")    ^ set("456")  == set(['1', '5', '6'])
bin(0b100100 ^ 0b000111)   == '0b100011'
#     1  4          456          1   56
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `s | set('ds')`, assuming `s = set('edhs')`

Answer (score 1):

First of all python tutorial is your the very best friend and contains all information you need. You can take a look at the following link to get more info about python set types: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.difference#set-types-set-frozenset

You can use set [union method](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.difference#set.union) for this purpose:

> union(other, ...) is the same as set | other | ...
>
> ```
> Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.
> ```

```
baseSet = set('abcd')
baseSet = baseSet.union('zx')
```

Or using set [update method](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.difference#set.update):

> update(other, ...) is the same as set |= other | ...
>
> ```
> Update the set, adding elements from all others.
> ```

```
baseSet = set('abcd')
baseSet.update('zx')
```